# Rails deployment issues when calling delayed_job:restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, delayed-job

When I try to run the following task to restart delayed_jobs on my server I get the error message below. **However**, without this script being run the deployment is successful and the application runs as is expected, so all the gems are installed correctly and rails 2.3.8 is the version installed on the server.

```
namespace :delayed_job do 
  desc "Restart the delayed_job process"
  task :restart, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job restart"
  end
end

# error
Missing the Rails 2.3.8 gem. Please `gem install -v=2.3.8 rails`, update your     RAILS_GEM_VERSION setting in config/environment.rb for the Rails version you do have installed, or comment out RAILS_GEM_VERSION to use the latest version installed.
```

All gems are installed using sudo (the /home/chris/.gem/... folder does not actually exist)

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.6.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /opt/ruby1.8/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /opt/ruby1.8/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /opt/ruby1.8/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /home/chris/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

The capistrano settings are setup so to perform the deployment with the 'chris' account.

Any ideas why it can't find the rails gem?

Comment: Can you access the Rails console (script/console production) from the machine (as the chris user)? If so, what does Gem.path return?

Comment: Yes the rails console loads fine and Gem.path returns the same paths that are shown when running `gem environment`.  The issue is that I can run the script when logged into the server, but not through capistrano, yet all deployment tasks work fine through capistrano.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), you may have to [execute the script in the context of your bundle](http://gembundler.com/man/bundle-exec.1.html). This will give your script awareness of the appropriate gems. It seems like even though your `gem env` gives you the correct gem path, your script may not be executing with the same environmental configuration.

```
run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec script/delayed_job restart"
```

Or, if you're not using bundler, you might check the output of `gem env` from within the task to confirm that the script is or is not using the correct environment configuration. Try checking the logs for the output of this command.

```
run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=production gem env"
```

My suspicion is that your `gem env` output will differ. You can also try listing the gems available to the task.

```
run "cd #{current_path}; RAILS_ENV=production gem list"
```

Lastly, you can examine the file `script/delayed_job` to see if it's pointing to a differing version of Ruby or Ruby on Rails config. Let us know if the these lines exist or look different:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))
```

**Additional References**

- [`gem` command](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/9)
- http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/9